# WCF logging: Why isn't Close being called for TraceListener?

Tags: .net, wcf, logging, tracelistener

I'm trying to log messages to my WCF service at transport level. I've followed some instructions I found on the net successfully, but now I want to implement my own trace listener that supports our in-house logging solution.

I've implemented a trace listener and I configure it using the `app.config` of my windows service hosting the WCF service. The following is the XML I use to configure the logging.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="messages" type="my.namespace.AdvancedLogTraceListener, Tools.Logging, Version=2.0.3.1, Culture=neutral" initializeData="C:\Logs" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

...

<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
  </messageLogging>
</diagnostics>
```

All of this works pretty well. However: Our in-house logging solution is used like a class. This class starts a background thread to perform actions like log-cleaning, do the actual logging asynchronously, etc. The class *requires* a method named `Close` to be called when closing the application, which stops the internal processing and exits the thread.

The `TraceListener` class, which my `TraceListener` inherits from, implements a `Close` method. I've overridden this method as follows:

```
public override void Close()
{
   base.Close();
   this.logFile.Close();
}
```

Only that it doesn't work. The `Close` method of the `TraceListener` does not seem to get called. What should I do to ensure that I can call my `Close` method when the application hosting the WCF service is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevers mind, I found another solution implementing message inspectors.

Comment: Care to detail that solution here so the rest of us can see how you resolved your issue?